# Delete or hide the data points' labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, factoextra

I have the dataframe below :

```
Val1<-c(0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9)
Val2<-c(0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9)
Val3<-c(0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9)
Val4<-c(0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9)
vales<-data.frame(Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4)
row.names(vales)<-c("asd","dasd","dfsdf","fdff")
```

which I process properly in order to create a cluster scatter plot with:

```
library(tidyverse)  # data manipulation
library(cluster)    # clustering algorithms
library(factoextra) # clustering algorithms & visualization
library(plotly)

cl<-scale(vales)
dist <- get_dist(cl)
k2 <- kmeans(cl, centers = 2, nstart = 25)

cl %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(cluster = k2$cluster,
         state = row.names(vales))

p2<-fviz_cluster(k2, data = cl)
p2+geom_text(aes(label=""))

#or
ggplotly(p2+geom_text(aes(label="")))
```

I want to delete the points' labels and I do not understand why they appear while in the case below they do not.

```
df <- USArrests
df <- na.omit(df)

df <- scale(df)
distance <- get_dist(df)

k2 <- kmeans(df, centers = 2, nstart = 25)
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(cluster = k2$cluster,
         state = row.names(USArrests))

p1 <- fviz_cluster(k2, geom = "point", data = df) + ggtitle("k = 2")
p1+geom_text(aes(label=""))


#or
ggplotly(p1+geom_text(aes(label="")))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the `geom` argument of `fviz_cluster` is `geom=c("point","text")`. By specifying `geom="point"`, labels are not displayed (`geom="text"` to only display labels).

```
fviz_cluster(k2, data = cl, geom="point")
```

Comment: I agree with this. So then, you don't need to use: `ggplotly(p2+geom_text(aes(label="")))`. `ggplotly(p2)` is enough for what you want.